# Updating Values in Map on the basis of other map in Java

Tags: java, dictionary

```
Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("k1", "v1");
map1.put("k2", "v2");
map1.put("k3", "v3");

Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map2.put("v1", "val1");
map2.put("v2", "val2");
map2.put("v3", "vav3");
```

I want to update values of **map1** so that it has entries:

- "k1" , "val1",
- "k2" , "val2",
- "k3" , "val3"

My solution:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map1.entrySet()) {
   map1.put(entry.getKey(), map2.get(entry.getValue()));
}
```

Is there any better way to do this?

> **Edit:** I am using Java 7 but curious to know if there any better way in Java 8.

Comment: Not really, no -- though it looks like you should be doing `map3.put` instead of `map1.put`?

Comment: is this java 8? in which case, streams can help you.

Comment: Also, you should be doing `map2.put` instead of `map1.put` when populating `map2`.

Comment: @njzk2 I'm not convinced Java 8 would let you make any significant improvements here.  If you were overwriting `map1` instead of populating `map3`, then maybe you could write `map1.replaceAll((k, v) -> map2.get(v))`, but that's the only improvement I can see.  Anything with streams would be more complicated than what's already here.

Comment: @LouisWasserman yes. I was starting to write a streams answer, but it is not very simple indeed.

Comment: What about values that doesn't match on each map? What to do whith then? ignore or remove?

Comment: @JorgeCampos In my case, all the values of map1 are present as a key in map2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with Java 8, you can just have

```
map1.replaceAll((k, v) -> map2.get(v));
```

[`replaceAll(function)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.BiFunction-) will replace all values from the map `map1` with the result of applying the given function. In this case, the function simply retrieves the value from `map2`.

Note that this solution has the same issues that your initial code: if `map2` doesn't have a corresponding mapping, `null` will be returned. You may want to call [`getOrDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-) to have a default value in that case.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    map1.put("k1", "v1");
    map1.put("k2", "v2");
    map1.put("k3", "v3");

    Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    map2.put("v1", "val1");
    map2.put("v2", "val2");
    map2.put("v3", "val3");

    map1.replaceAll((k, v) -> map2.get(v));

    System.out.println(map1); // prints "{k1=val1, k2=val2, k3=val3}"
}
```

Comment: Any comment for Java 7?

Comment: @devツ Honestly, apart from the case I mentioned (the map doesn't have the corresponding key), there isn't really room for improvement. It's fine as it is.

Answer (score 1):

For Java 7 there is nothing more that you can do, you are already doing it in the best way possible.

I'm adding this answer as a reference to show that for such case using Lambda Expressions in Java 8 will be even worst. See this example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    final Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();

    for ( int i=0; i<100000; i++ ){
        map1.put("k"+i, "v"+i);
        map2.put("v"+i, "val"+i);
    }

    long time;
    long prev_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map1.entrySet()) {
       map1.put(entry.getKey(), map2.get(entry.getValue()));
    }
    time = System.currentTimeMillis() - prev_time;
    System.out.println("Time after for loop " + time);


    map1 = new HashMap<>();
    for ( int i=0; i<100000; i++ ){
        map1.put("k"+i, "v"+i);
    }

    prev_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    map1.replaceAll((k, v) -> map2.get(v));
    time = System.currentTimeMillis() - prev_time;
    System.out.println("Time after for loop " + time);
}
```

The output for this will be:

```
Time after for loop 40
Time after for loop 100
```

The second loop is variable but always bigger than the first one.

I'm not Lambda specialist but I guess that there are more to be processed with it than a plain "foreach" of the first scenario

Running this test case over and over you will get for lambda almost always twice the time of the first "foreach" case.

Answer (score 0):

in Java 8 you can write:

```
map1.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .map(entry -> new SimpleEntry(entry.getKey(), map2.get(entry.getValue())))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(entry -> entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
```

Not the nicest thing, though, but still a non-mutating solution.

Comment: any better way in Java7 ?